# Kubernetes provisioning PVC from GCE Persistent disk volume shows error

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, persistent-volumes

I am using a GCE cluster with 2 nodes, which I set up using kubeadm. Now I want to set up a persistent volume for postgresql to be deployed. I created a PVC and PV with a storageClass and also created a disk space with 10G in name **postgres** in the same project.Iam attaching the scripts for the PVC,PV,and Deployment below.Also I am using a service account that have the access to the disks.

1.Deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment 
metadata:
  name: kyc-postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: "postgres:9.6.2"
        name: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: postgres
        volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/db-data
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: kyc-postgres-pvc
```

2.PersistentVolumeClaim.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: kyc-postgres-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: standard
```

3.PersistentVolume.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: kyc-postgres-pv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/createdby: gce-pd-dynamic-provisioner
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: kyc-postgres-pvc
    namespace: default
  gcePersistentDisk:
    fsType: NTFS
    pdName: postgres
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
          operator: In
          values:
          - us-central1-a
        - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region
          operator: In
          values:
          - us-central1-a
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: standard
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Bound
```

4. StorageClass.yml

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  zone: us-central1-a
```

Now when I create these volumes and deployments, the pod is not getting started properly.Iam getting the following errors when I tired creating deployments.

```
Failed to get GCE GCECloudProvider with error <nil>
```

Also Iam attaching my output for `kubectl get sc`

```
NAME       PROVISIONER            RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
standard   kubernetes.io/gce-pd   Delete          Immediate           false                  10m
```

Can someone help me with this.Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over- or under-emphasised a specific point let me know in the comments.

Comment: Can you add the output of `kubectl get sc` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `PersistentVolumeClaim` does not specify a `storageClassName`, so I suppose you may want to use the default *StorageClass*. When using a default StorageClass, you don't need to create a `PersistentVolume` resource, that will be provided dynamically from the Google Cloud Platform. (Or is there any specific reason you don't want to use the default StorageClass?)

Comment: Thanks for the response.Actually I missed out specifying the storageClassName in the PerisistentVolumeClaim.Also I belive when I use StorageClass I am opting for dynamic provisioning of disk.So are you telling when I use the above mentioned StoragClass (I have added storage class,please have look),I need not create a disk manually and write a PersistentVolume resource file.?

Comment: You don't need to create a `PersistentVolume` and you are fine with the _default_  `StorageClass` as whar I understand. So you don't need to specify a `storageClassName`. This works out of the box with GKE. Unless you want specific needs, e.g. using a _regional disk_ or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Using the GCECloudProvider in Kubernetes outside of the Google Kubernetes Engine has the following prerequisites :

1. The VM needs to be run with a service account that has the right to provision disks. Info on how to run a VM with a service account can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances)
2. The Kubelet needs to run with the `argument --cloud-provider=gce`. For this the `KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS` in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` have to be edited. The Kubelet can then be restarted with `sudo systemctl restart kubelet`
3. The Kubernetes cloud-config file needs to be configured. The file can be found at `/etc/kubernetes/cloud-config` and the following content is enough to get the cloud provider to work:

   ```
   [Global]

   project-id = "<google-project-id>"
   ```
4. Kubeadm needs to have GCE configured as its [cloud provider](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#kubeadm).However, the [nodeName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#node-name-3) has to be changed. Edit the config file and upload it to cluster via `kubeadm config upload from-file`

   ```
   cloudProvider: gce
   ```

Comment: In the 3rd step, I have 4 files,admin.conf,controller-manager.conf
,kubelet.conf,scheduler.conf. In which file I must add the project Id and should I do this in all nodes?

Comment: cloud-config file need to be created(if it does not exist) and passed in via --cloud-config specified in the command lines for the kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager and the kubelet. Since kubelet runs in each node it needs to be done in each node only for kubelet